# Does FragmentTabHost need TabWidget to be defined explicitly

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-tabs

I'm trying to implement an Activity with 3 tabs on it. I decided to use FragmentTabHost for this purpose. I've found some code examples with following layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TabWidget 
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"/>
    </android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>

    <FrameLayout 
        android:id="@+id/realtabcontent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />      
</LinearLayout>
```

But I was surprised when understood that previous code sample works the same way without TabWidget:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>

    <FrameLayout 
        android:id="@+id/realtabcontent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

I just see my tabs as intended. According to the source code for [FragmentTabHost](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/v4/java/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTabHost.java), it creates TabWidget by itself if could not find it in the hierarchy of views. So I wonder if I should declare TabWidget explicitly in my layout file or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the behavior that you describe is not documented, so there's a slight risk of regression if they drop this feature someday. Of course, having the `TabWidget` child is also undocumented, since the documentation for `FragmentTabHost` sucks.

You might also put the `TabWidget` in your layout if you want declarative control, via XML attributes, of some aspects of the `TabWidget` rendering.

Otherwise, though, if the default generated `TabWidget` works for you, you are welcome to use it.

Comment: Thanks for the fast and complete response. You're right. TabWidget and FragmentTabHost documentation lacks some details.